# Fade in effect on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fade

I am trying to make my homepage consistently have a fade in effect when this loads. however, it only works part of the time. This is the current script I am using. I set it to html, since individual div elements didn't seem to work, but setting it to html does and doesn't.

```
$(document).ready(function () { $('html').hide().fadeIn(1500).delay(6000)});
```

Comment: We are going to need to see a live example of it not working.. or just more coding.

Comment: What happens when it fails?

Comment: Yes, and what I mean does and doesn't it that it fades in sometimes and sometimes it just statically loads without fading in.

Comment: Nevermind, I got it working. Allocated the script to load first before other scripts.

Comment: Don't forget to answer your own question so this doesn't appear unanswered.

Comment: Did that now, thanks for the tip.

Comment: @Blake I tried your script http://jsfiddle.net/TsYr7/ ... It's working fine..

Comment: Yeah, the problem was I set the script to load after other scripts. rearranged and it works every time now. Thanks for testing it out though.

Answer (score 2):

set to priority before other scripts.

```
 $(document).ready(function () { $('body').hide().fadeIn(1500).delay(6000)});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the below code. It will work:

Set ur body first:

```
<body>
This is my page
</body>
```

Now the jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){$("body").hide().fadeIn(1000);});
```

Answer (score 2):

Check out some Loading effect at CODROPS Article ..
u may find it useful
http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/09/18/creative-loading-effects/

Answer (score 0):

It won't work if the page loads too slow.

Maybe a lot of images(large photos), scripts etc.

Or just because the slow internet connection.

Comment: Here is a example(change the placeholdit's image size and run):
http://jsfiddle.net/6QYke/1/